# mustache JS html in condition

Tags: javascript, mustache

I am using mustache JS. To check the values of the elements in the string list in html.

Sample

```
{
   "musketeers": ["Athos", "Aramis", "Porthos", "DiArtagnan"]
}

{{#musketeers}} 
  {{.}}
{{/musketeers}}



{{.}} == "Athos" true
```

ForExample 
Angular 2+ such as:

```
*ngIf="musketeers[0]=='Athos'" ==> True
*ngIf="musketeers[1]=='Athos'" ==> false
```

Thank you.